# Will EventBus.post() deliver event if configChanges occur or if activity in background?

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

I read documentation [here](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/EventBus%2Fsrc%2Fde%2Fgreenrobot%2Fevent%2FEventBus.java) but there is no clear explanation will event trigger if configChanges occur in activity or if activity in background with `EventBus.getDefault().post()` . Now I'm using EventBus like this:

```
EventBus.getDefault.postSticky(new SomeEvent());

public void onEventMainThread(SomeEvent someEvent){
        EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(someEvent);

}
```

I would like to avoid this boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Activity` will obviously not receive any events between `unregister()` in `onDestroy()` and `register()` in `onCreate()` - remember that by default the `Activity` will be fully recreated when configuration changes. However, if you `registerSticky()` then you'll have access to the latest published event, even if it arrived at the moment of `Activity` recreation.

Comment: Right! That mean if I don't want to keep this sticky event after next configChanges should I remove it?

Comment: If you don't care about the event after configChanges - then you don't need to use sticky events in the first place. They add some overhead as they're caching events, so be sure to use this approach only if justified.